# $4$ females and $6$ males will be seated on $19$ chairs

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

There are $4$ females and $6$ males students. They will be seated on $19$ chairs. How many ways can we do this, if no two females are seated in adjacent chairs?

What makes me confused is there are only $10$ students but the chairs are $19$.

If the chairs are $10$ only (equal to the number of persons) I could do $C(7,4)\cdot 4!6!$

Comment: So there are a lot of empty seats.  For the first part, just place the women, so $\binom {19}4$, and then place the men, $\binom {15}6$. (and then assign people). Can you finish from here?

Comment: But, the females are not adjacent.

Comment: Do you have the answer? Compare it with 157405248000, if it's so, trust my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of thinking it: First seat the men then seat the women. And arrange people in the right order before seating.

---

> \begin{align}P(15,6)\cdot P(16,4)\\=\boxed{{15\choose6}6!\cdot{16\choose4}4!}\end{align}

---

It may sounds creepy, but here is another hint if you don't get it:

> \begin{align}\textrm{Beyond those people, there are identical 9 ghost there(to help you)}\end{align}

---

The key idea is about the $15$ and $16$:

- 15: this comes from 19-4, why? because I first consider those 6 men and 9 ghosts.
- 16: now we finish the queuing of 6+9=15 men-ghost-queue, what's the next step to make girls no adjacent?

Comment: But the females are not adjacent

Comment: @MuhamadAbdulRosid: That's considered in my answer.

Comment: I know there are 9 ghosts. But, why is it C(15,6) why 15? I don't understand. Then why C(16,4)? Where does it come from? The 16

Comment: @MuhamadAbdulRosid: Correct, that's what want you to think, that's the key idea/value of this problem, you're on the right path, I will edit for clarification.

Comment: @MuhamadAbdulRosid  Lining up $15$ objects in a row creates $16$ spaces in which an object can be placed, $14$ between successive objects and two at the ends of the row.

Answer (score 2):

Total Number of chairs=19.

Total number of persons=10.

So number of possible to select 10 chairs from 19 chairs $=19C10$.

Now take 10 chairs.

Then

$_B_B_B_B_B_B_$

If you're filling 4 girls in any 4 spaces among 7 spaces yiels a required arrangements.
There are $7C4$ ways to choose filling 4 girls.

Thus totally we have
$19C10×7C4×4!×6!$ ways.

Where $4!$ represents PERMUTATION among 4 girls and $6!$ represents PERMUTATION among 6 boys.

Comment: I think you miss a case: if [girl, empty, girl], then there are no adjacent girls. That is: if the choice of those 10 chairs in you $19C10$, accidentally, choose some two chairs that are not adjacent, then even if your $7C4$ have two girl (seems like) adjacent, they actually not.

Comment: @IsanaYashiro if the empty girl means you leave the space and merge the boys

Comment: sorry, it's a typo, I meant girl - empty - girl.

Comment: @IsanaYashiro OP gave that condition that No two girls be adjacent.   If you are filling like G-empty-G-G-G means it represents an arrangement GBBGBGBGBB

Comment: I meant: if your $19C10$ are not adjacent, your idea start from "Then _B_..." is incorrect, for whether if there is already separation between chairs, no need to use boy(s) as separator(s).

Comment: @IsanaYashiro yes sir. I got it. Thank you so much. I will fix this issue soon. Once again thank you.

Comment: No worries, cheers for the love for combinatorics~

Answer (score 2):

Let's first sit the females... For that first select $4$ chairs to them: ${19 \choose 4}$. Now we have left $19-4$ chairs remaining. Let's then distribute the remaining chairs between the females to help us with the restriction that no two females are seated in adjacent... For that, think as the females as separators, therefore:
$$
\underbrace{ }_\text{slot 1}\text{ female 1}\underbrace{ }_\text{slot 2}\text{ female 2}\underbrace{ }_\text{slot 3}\text{ female 3}\underbrace{ }_\text{slot 4}\text{ female 4}\underbrace{ }_\text{slot 5}
$$
where slots 2, 3 and 4 need to have at least one chair. From that we can create the following equation:
$$
\underbrace{s_1}_{\geq 0 }+\underbrace{s_2}_{\geq 1 }+\underbrace{s_3}_{\geq 1}+\underbrace{s_4}_{\geq 1}+
\underbrace{s_5}_{\geq 0} = 19-4 = 15
$$
using stars and bars method we get that we can distribute the chairs in those slots in ${16 \choose 4}$ ways.

Now we've just sat 4 females and distributed the remaining $15$ chairs according to our restriction. Let's then choose $6$ of those $15$ chairs to sit the males. We can do that in ${15 \choose 6}$ ways.

Finally we have males and females sitting in a way that between two females we're going to have or chairs or males to separate them. We just need to organize them in all possible ways now: $4!6!$.

And our final answer, by multiplication principle is:
$$
{19 \choose 4}{16 \choose 4}{15 \choose 6}4!6!
$$

**EDIT**:

As Isana noticed in the comments, the ${19 \choose 4}$ at first is not needed since the distribution of chairs, at second step of the reasoning, will determine the position of the females. Therefore the corrected answer is:
$$
{16 \choose 4}{15 \choose 6}4!6!
$$

Comment: I think you made a mistake: if your ${19\choose4}$ choose position(s) at the left end and/or the right end, then your assumption of slot1 slot5 not exists

Comment: @Isana Yashiro No, they do exists, but they don't have the positivity restriction.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is the easiest for me to understand. Really helpfull

Comment: Apologies for my first question, you're right. But another issue: your first $19\choose4$ is not needed, think like this: your slot12345 decide the position of those 4 females, then we have the same answer:)

Comment: @Isana yeah, you are right! Thanks for pointing it out. I've edited it.

Comment: @Muhamad you're welcome. Consider marking it as an accepted answer? Ty anyway. That's a good question!

Comment: Wow, I don't even know that. The selection of 4 chairs out of 19 chairs isn't needed right?

Comment: @Muhamad yeah, it's not needed. Following the steps of my reasoning... You'll see that it doesn't matter what chairs the females picked at the beginning, because what is really marking their position is the distribution of the chairs at the second step!

Comment: Initially, you are choosing four of four slots for the women, which is why the factor of $\binom{19}{4}$ is not needed.